# get contacts from phone using react native expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to get contact numbers from the phone using expo react native. after accessing the contacts object. The phone numbers are in the phoneNumber array. The array has a series of objects and each object has the digits in the digits key. My action creator is below that will store the data in database for now. I will change it to local storage later. 
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/contacts.html#content

```
export const setContacts = (contacts) => async dispatch => {
  //  set the contacts object into firebase and load it into redux
  //  contacts is an array of objects; convert it object with key phone number
  //  key should be phoneNumbers; phoneNumbers is an array of phone numbers
  //  function below converts array to object to save to database with key for each object
  // whenever getting information outside app validate and format for storage into db
  console.log(contacts, 'this is the contacts object inside setContacts action');

  //  filter contacts that don't have phoneNumber
  const arrayToObject = (array, keyField) =>
    array.filter(item => item[keyField].length !== 0)
      .map(item2 => {
        const item3 = item2;
        item3.keyField = item2.keyField
          .filter(item => item.digits.length === 10 || item.digits.length === 11)
          .map(item4 => {
            const item5 = item4;
            item5.digits = item4.digits.length === 11 ?
              item4.digits.substr(1) : item4.digits;
            return item5;
          });
        return item3;
      })
      .reduce((object, item) => {
        const accumulator = object;
        accumulator[`${item[keyField][0].digits}`] = item.name;
        return accumulator;
      }, {});
  // object of objects to save in db
  const phoneNumbers = 'phoneNumbers';
  const contactsObject = arrayToObject(contacts, phoneNumbers);
  console.log(contactsObject, 'this is the contactsObject inside setContacts action');
  // save into firebase
  const user = await firebase.auth().currentUser;
  if (user !== null) {
    await firebase.database().ref(`/users/${user.uid}/contacts`)
      .set(contactsObject)
      .then(() => console.log('contactsObject set into /users/uid/contacts inside setContacts action'))
      .catch((e) => console.error(e));
    console.log(contactsObject, 'contactsObject inside setContacts action before dispatch');
    dispatch({ type: CONTACTS, payload: contactsObject });
  } else {
    console.log('user object was not found inside setContacts action');
  }
};
```

the above code doesn't work. I think there is error in my logic specifically the arraytoObject function. i just need help with fixing the cod

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: the above code doesn't work. I think there is error in my logic specifically the arraytoObject function. i just need help with fixing the code